# Can I change job after 6 months?

Tags: job-search

I worked in 2 Mechanical companies in span of 6 years. 2 years at one place and 4 years at other company. Then I switched to IT and joined a startup at low payment as I was fresher in IT. Now I have completed 6 months here but the environment is not good as well as pay is bare minimum.

Can I change jobs after 6 months without giving potential employers the wrong impression?

Answer (score 2):

No one is going to stop you. The next employer will be asking why are you switching the job within 6 months. You should have a compelling reason to tell them. That's all.

I am assuming the employer is Indian, make a note of minimum stay and notice period.

Comment: I m concerning about I m just fresher in this field so it shouldn't get wrong impression to next employer

Comment: You have compelling reasons - not a good environment, and low pay. Plus you have six years of workplace experience in other jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Look for a new job now. You really have nothing to lose.

Just don't quit your current job until you've secured a new job first. It's always easier to find a new job when you're already employed.

But this next time around, don't accept the first job that's offered. Be more selective in your search. Think about the type of environment you want to work in. Don't be afraid to ask tough questions. You don't want to make a habit of switching jobs every six months.